# Xamarin.Forms.WebView initial loading indicator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the simplest way for me to take a Xamarin forms WebView and add a loading progress bar for the first load?

My application simply wraps a website but in poor bandwidth scenarios when the splash screen disappears and the WebView is loading it's content I of course see a white screen.

I would like to see a progress indicator. I have looked around but haven't found a simple solution to this and most questions are not oriented towards Xamarin.Forms.

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `StackLayout` with `ActivityIindicator` and `WebView` as children and set it's visibility based on IsWorking property value which is set in **`WebView.Navigating`** and **`WebView.Navigated`** events. Your ViewModel has to implement `IOnPropertyChanged`.

```net
var webViewView = new WebView() {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
};
webViewView.SetBinding<YourViewModel>(View.IsVisibleProperty, v => v.IsWorking, 
    BindingMode.OneWay, new Converters.NegateBoolConverter());

webViewView.Navigating += (sender, e) => {
    viewModel.IsWorking = true;
};

webViewView.Navigated += (sender, e) => {
    viewModel.IsWorking = false;
};

var activityIndicator = new ActivityIndicator() {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
};
activityIndicator.SetBinding<YourViewModel>(ActivityIndicator.IsRunningProperty, v => v.IsWorking);

var isWorkingView = new ContentView() {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Content = activityIndicator
};
isWorkingView.SetBinding<YourViewModel>(ContentView.IsVisibleProperty, v => v.IsWorking);

var root = new StackLayout() {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Children = {
        webViewView,
        isWorkingView,
    }
};
```

Comment: I found the Navigating event doesn't fire as soon as the WebView starts its request to the web i.e. as soon at you set the URL. I used the ContentPage's Appearing event instead.